# What's questionnaire-based UI called?

Tags: terminology

Usually seen in self-service chat windows, the user selects the problem area, and it responds with more detailed categories to pin-point the problem, taking the user through a workflow of diagnostics without user needing to type anything. What is this called and are there ready-made tools to design these workflows?

How can I help you today?

1. Credit card
2. Banking

And the user usually just have to click on the relevant menu items. I want to design some simple questions to answer colleague's computer problems.

Answer (score 1):

These things are usualy called **Wizard**s, or **multi-step flow**s. [Nielsen has some recommendations on how to use them](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/wizards/).

Answer (score 1):

While a Wizard answers the question correctly. I also think that **Conversational User Interfaces with suggested inputs** fits the scenario described in the question.

[image]

The benefit of this over a wizard would be that, you **do not have to worry about the total number of steps** (like step 3 of 5). It can be dynamic.

Comment: Also called a menu or button-based chatbot. https://www.ibm.com/blog/chatbot-types/

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [chatbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatbot) (which is a conversational user interface method applied to a wizard, as others have pointed out).